# how to pass server side value to client side after event handler completed ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I have a 'LinkButton' in GridView. when click on it, I want to popup a window. so when I click the linkbutton, onClientClick triggers first. but I want to wait the hidden field value being set in code behind, then pass the hidden value as an arg of my popup window.but now, the hidden field value is always null. So how can I make this work? Thanks.

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // load something
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //set hidden feild value
        hdfilename.Value = "something";
    }
</script>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetSelectedRow(sender) {
            if (!sender) return;

            var hrefToEvalWhenFinished = sender.attributes['href'].value; // Ext.get(sender).getAttribute('href');

            if (hrefToEvalWhenFinished) {
                // todo: do async work here

                // Fire the links HREF event which will do the postback.
                eval(hrefToEvalWhenFinished);
                var filename = document.getElementById("<% =hdfilename.ClientID %>").value;
                if (filename) {
                    window.open('/Blank.aspx?f=filename', 'popUpWindow', 'height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
            OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' CommandName="ViewDocument" OnClientClick="return GetSelectedRow(this);" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfilename" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `GridView1_RowCommand` firing? Check your debugger.

Comment: yes. rowCommand is fired

Comment: I'm positive GridView1_RowCommand fires after OnClientClick.

Comment: I know GridView1_RowCommand  is fired. but it fires after OnClientClick finished. I want it comes back to 'OnClientClick' code after GridView1_RowCommand completed. then I can see the hidden field 'hdfilename' value in 'OnClientClick' JavaScript code

Comment: Use `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` to call `GetSelectedRow()` in your `GridView1_RowCommand` method, and get rid of the `OnClientClick` attribute.

Comment: Actually, I was coming from using 'ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock' to call JavaScript to popup window. everything works fine on my local testing. but once publish to server, the popup window won't occur. but it works fine with directly call Javascript code to popup window on server.

Comment: Check your browser's console, see if you see any errors. Also check to make sure your script block actually gets rendered.